# Profiling only the plugin

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, profiling

When profiling my dll plugin using:

```
Analyze -> Profiler -> Attach/Detach
```

VS 2012 is also including all the dlls that are being used by the target program which is attached the profiler, like the graphics drivers, opengl drivers, MSVCR110.dll, etc.

This clutters the report with unnecessary information and libraries, and it makes difficult to find the hotspot in my plugin, it's even difficult to find the plugin functions.

Question: Can I profile only the functions that are in my plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching debbuger to the process is standard operation that loads symbols for all modules and "attaches" to them. I couldn't find any solution to 'disable' other modules for profiler.